# Is it safe to replace a ceramic fuse with a radial one?

Tags: fuses, ceramic

I have to repair a led tv with a blown fuse. On the power board the fuse required is a T4.0AH/250V fuse, but I couldn't find it at the shop. They gave me instead a radial fuse, claiming that it's the same.
Is it possible to replace a ceramic fuse with a radial one or could blown other parts of the board?

[image]

Comment: When you say a ceramic fuse, do you mean a HRC fuse?

Comment: If rated for 250Vac and has line filter OK to suppress 4kV transients

Comment: Data sheets required for both parts.

Comment: The term "ceramic fuse" is nearly meaningless, except perhaps within the narrow context of the type of consumer electronics you're working on.  If you don't have a datasheet, post a picture.

Comment: No, fuses have specs that need to be matched, without seeing the application or info on the fuses this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4.0AH/250V stands for "slow acting, 4 A, high breaking capacity, 250 V voltage rating".

The one you got just says "4 A" and unless there are other markings on it not in the photo, there is no way to tell if it is an acceptable replacement (so it isn't 8-).

Comment: Ok but is it possible to use a radial fuse as replacement for a ceramic one? I mean what's the practical difference between them?

Comment: If all the specs are the same, then yes, it is possible. Ceramic fuses tend to have a much higher breaking capacity, though, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_%28electrical%29#Breaking_capacity .

Comment: One is ceramic, the other is round -- and then there's all the possible things that could be different inside, that you can -- practically -- only tell with detailed specifications.  So yes, you can replace "a ceramic fuse" with **exactly the right** radial fuse -- or you can replace "a ceramic fuse" with another ceramic fuse that's totally wrong, and it'll utterly fail at its job.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that some random 4A fuse the shopkeeper has on hand (lacking any safety approval markings, at that) will match the characteristics of the ceramic fuse in terms of breaking capacity (perhaps 400A rating) and time delay characteristics.

So there is some risk of it nuisance blowing or not providing proper protection.